# How do I test an array of strings to find if a specific string is in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this part of my code so far. It compiles fine and runs fine. But If I choose to insert a Rank that isn't in the list it still prints the value that I input.

```
private String         Rank;  //string r
private static String[] Ranks = {"Assistant", "Associate", "Full"};

public professor(String n, int a, int s, String r, int nc, int pp)
{
    super(n, a, s);
    setRank(r);
    setNumCo(nc);
    setPubPaps(pp);
}
//mutator to set the Rank and check to make sure it is in the string list
public void setRank(String r)
{
    boolean check = false;

    List valid = Arrays.asList(this.Ranks);

    if(valid.contains(r)) 
        check = true;

    if(check = true)
        this.Rank = r;
    else
        this.Rank = "Associate";
}
```

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
 professor p2 = new professor ("Muench", 50, 222344455, "False", 3, 45);
```

"False" is definitely not in the list of ranks but it will still print as follows in my print window
False professor Muench....

Comment: `if(check = true)` What do you think happens here?

Comment: use == instead of =  where you have (check = true).  You use = for assigning a value and you use == for comparisons hope that helps

Comment: if check is true then is should be one of the ranks from the array. If not I want it to just change the rank to Associate. But thanks Ronan that worked

Comment: Also, there is no reason for the variable `check`. Simply use the actual condition `valid.contains(r)` in the second `if`

Comment: Consider using an `enum` to represent the rank. The method collapses to a simple assignment (and maybe a null check).

Comment: @GaryHanley *"if check is true"* why do you think it does a comparison there?

Comment: What we are trying to tell you is: `check == true` evaluates whether check is true, while `check = true` sets it to true. Imho you should not do `if(check == true)`, since `if(check)` is exactly is the same

Comment: I understand that now, I completely looked over that I was setting check to equal instead of comparing it. I completely just disregarded the boolean check because it isn't necessary for this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

writing it like this will work and a lot more readable

```
List valid = Arrays.asList(this.Ranks);

if(valid.contains(r)) 
    this.Rank = r;
else
    this.Rank = "Associate";
```

This works because the .contains method returns a boolean value so you basically end up with `if(true)`  or `if(false)` when the value is returned

Comment: Still suggesting to use raw-types is _always_  bad. Either remove that part or _even better_ fix it for him.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(valid.contains(r)) 
        check = true;

    if(check == true)
        this.Rank = r;
    else
        this.Rank = "Associate";
```

Comment: Please add why this is the answer to the question. It might not be obvious from just seeing the code block.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using your array of strings (without converting the array to a list):

```
public void setRank(String r)
{
  for ( final String rank : professor.Ranks ) // Static reference to Ranks class variable.
  {
    if ( rank.equals( r ) )
    {
      this.Rank = r;
      return;
    }
  }
  this.Rank = "Associate";
}
```

You also have an odd naming convention:

- the class `professor` is entirely in lower case when it is usual to capitalise (or camel-case) class names.
- the attribute `Rank` is capitolised when the normal convention is to use lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Java 8**

If case sensitive

```
public void setRank(String r){
       this.Rank = Stream.of(Ranks).filter(p->p.equals(r)).findAny().orElse("Associate");
}
```

If not case sensitive

```
public void setRank(String r){
       this.Rank = Stream.of(Ranks).filter(p->p.equalsIgnoreCase(r)).findAny().orElse("Associate");
}
```